# No matching member function to call for 'push_back' error

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, member-functions

While implementing LRU cache got this error.
Earlier I was implementing it via maps it works then but somehow even when doing it as vector it does not work.

```
#include <list>
class LRUCache {
    list<pair<int,int>> lru;
    int cap;
    vector<list<pair<int, int>>::iterator> hash;
public:
LRUCache(int capacity) {
    cap = capacity;
    for(int i=0;i<=3000;i++)
        hash.push_back(nullptr);
}

int get(int key) {
    if(hash[(key)]!=nullptr)
    {
        int v = hash[key]->first;
        lru.erase(hash[key]);
        lru.push_front({v,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
        return v;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

void put(int key, int value) {
    if(hash[(key)]!=nullptr)
    {
        int v = value;
        lru.erase(hash[key]);
        lru.push_front({v,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
    }
    else if(lru.size()<cap)
    {
        lru.push_front({value,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
    }
    else
    {
        lru.push_front({value,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
        auto it = lru.end();
        it--;
        hash[(it->second)] = nullptr;
        lru.erase(it);
    }
}
};
```

This way does not work either.

```
vector<list<pair<int, int>>::iterator> hash(3001,NULL);
```

Can we not create a vector of pointers?

Comment: You can create vector of pointers, but `std::list::iterator` is not a pointer.

Comment: You can't push `nullptr` into a vector of `iterator`s if `iterator` is not implemented as a raw pointer (which is never a guarantee). You probably want a vector of `pair<int, int>*` pointers instead of `iterator`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an iterator variable, instead of `nullptr` value, as bellow:

```cpp
list<pair<int, int>>::iterator emptyIt;  // this iterator object refer to nothing

// Using `emptyIt` to initialize the hash
LRUCache(int capacity) {
    cap = capacity;
    for(int i=0;i<=3000;i++)
        hash.push_back(emptyIt);
}

// Using emptyIt instead of nullptr
int get(int key) {
    if(hash[(key)]!=emptyIt)
    {
        int v = hash[key]->first;
        lru.erase(hash[key]);
        lru.push_front({v,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
        return v;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

void put(int key, int value) {
    if(hash[(key)]!=emptyIt)
    {
        int v = value;
        lru.erase(hash[key]);
        lru.push_front({v,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
    }
    else if(lru.size()<cap)
    {
        lru.push_front({value,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
    }
    else
    {
        lru.push_front({value,key});
        hash[key] = lru.begin();
        auto it = lru.end();
        it--;
        hash[(it->second)] = emptyIt;
        lru.erase(it);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: It does work any place where I can read why nullptr does not work or some similar idea of how to create a vector and when it can't take some default value?

Comment: Plus why can't we initialize it at the constructor?